# Unite endpoints of edge with line

Tags: matlab, image-recognition, edge-detection, centroid

I'm trying to make an object recognition program using a k-NN classifier. I've got a bunch of images for the training part of the classifier and a bunch of images to recognize. Those images are in grayscale and there's an object (only its edge) per image. I need to calculate their center of mass so I use
`img=im2bw(img)`
 and then `regionprops(img,'centroid')`.

The problem is that some of those edges aren't closed so regionprops doesn't work then. I tried eroding the image (the edge is black, white background) but the endlines of those edges are too apart from eachother. I tried using `bwmorph` function to do so but still can't make it work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm adding some images in case anyone wants to try:
[image: tree_1]

[image: square_1][image: tree_2]

Comment: does [bwconvhull](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconvhull.html) solve your problem?

Comment: No, the edge disappearead when I used `imgc=bwconvhull(img)` or `imgc=bwconvhull(img,'objects')` or `imgc=bwconvhull(img,'union')`

Answer (score 0):

### Use morphological operation

Use a closing operation to make your structures filled.

#### 1. As first step prepare your image data

```
im = imread('your image.jpg');
% Get first channel as gray scale information
im = im(:,:,1);
% Threshold it for simplicyty, you may work on grayscale too.
im1 = logical(im > 128);
```

[image: Image after binarisation]

#### 2. Use a simple block shaped structuring element

The structuring element is defined by:

```
strel=ones(3,3);
```

You may use disk shaped elements or whatever gives the best result to you.

#### 3. Apply structuring element a couple of times

Apply the strel a couple of times with an erosion operator to your original image to close your figure:

```
for i=1:20
  im1 = imerode(im1,strel);
end
```

[image: Image after erosion]

#### 4. Dilate the image to get back to original shape

Next step is to dilate the image to get back to your original outer shape:

```
for i=1:20
  im1 = imdilate(im1,strel);
end
```

### Final result

The final result should be suitable to get a sufficiently precise center or gravity.

[image: Image after dilation]